# Write IF..ELSE in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a table looked like this

```
mysql> select * from rc;

    +----+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
    | id | business_date              | cutoff_dt                  | recon_dt                   |
    +----+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
    |  1 | 2017-03-21 16:50:29.032000 | 2017-03-21 16:50:31.441000 | 2017-03-21 16:50:32.832000 |
    +----+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to run query

-Select * from `rc` where `business_date = '2017-03-17'
- if`cutoff_dt` is null or empty, it will display null, otherwise display not null

I wrote it into shell script.

```
#! /bin/bash
mysql -u root -p <<rcard
use rcard;
SELECT * 
(CASE WHEN (cut_off_dt = "NULL")
    THEN
      echo "Null"
    ELSE
       echo "NOT NULL"
END)
from rc WHERE business_date = '2017-03-17';
rcard
```

But I get error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(CASE WHEN (cut_off_dt = "NULL")
    THEN
      echo "Null"
    ELSE
   ' at line 2
```

Is it the correct way to write the IF ELSE in MySQL ?

Comment: Ubuntu tag? This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct way to check for `NULL` values.

Try this:

```
SELECT *,
       IF(mepslog_cut_off_dt IS NULL, 'NULL', 'NOT NULL')  
from rc_mepslog 
WHERE mepslog_business_date = '2017-03-17';
```

You can alternatively use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE 
          WHEN mepslog_cut_off_dt IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
          ELSE 'NOT NULL'
       END
from rc_mepslog 
WHERE mepslog_business_date = '2017-03-17';
```

Comment: If I want to do the update query when the `cut_off_dt` is null, I can use this method too ?

Comment: @AI. Yes you can

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN (mepslog_cut_off_dt IS NULL)
    THEN
      'Null'
    ELSE
       'NOT NULL' END) from rc WHERE business_date = '2017-03-17'
```

To compare if the value is null, use `column IS NULL` instead of `column = 'NULL'`; the latter would check if the column you are comparing has the string 'null'

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing comma after `select *` and none of your table names you specified in the query exists. To separate a table from the column, you use a dot `.`. There are  other wrong written column names appart from that. Also, you don't use `echo`, you simply specify what to do. Also, I'd suggest to use an alias for the selected column from the case (`AS 'nullOrNotNull'`)

```
SELECT * ,
CASE WHEN cut_off_dt IS NULL
    THEN
      'Null'
    ELSE
      'NOT NULL'
END AS 'nullOrNotNull'
from rc WHERE business_date = '2017-03-17';
```

Comment: Do you have any idea for this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931666/update-query-wrong-in-mysql